# Upload a file to Nodejs using python request

Tags: python, node.js, file, upload

I got some help here on the nodejs side: [Extract file from POST request nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43264772/extract-file-from-post-request-nodejs)

I am new to node, and I am having problems getting this file
node.js (Server PC)

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer')

var app = express();
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

/* POST commands */
app.post('/upload', upload.array(), function (req, res, next) {
console.log("I AM HERE");
})
```

python script (Client PC)

```
files = {'file': ('test_file', open(filePath, 'rb'))}
r = requests.post("http://192.168.2.39:3000/upload", files=files)
```

What am I doing wrong here? thanks

I am getting error 500,

## Unexpected field

```
Error: Unexpected field
    at makeError (C:\qa\Automation\MyProj\Python Automation\Utilities\node\MyProjrtu\node_modules\multer\lib\make-error.js:12:13)
    at wrappedFileFilter (C:\qa\Automation\MyProj\Python Automation\Utilities\node\MyProjrtu\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
    at Busboy.<anonymous> (C:\qa\Automation\MyProj\Python Automation\Utilities\node\MyProjrtu\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
    at emitMany (events.js:127:13)
    at Busboy.emit (events.js:201:7)
    at Busboy.emit (C:\qa\Automation\MyProj\Python Automation\Utilities\node\MyProjrtu\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
    at PartStream.<anonymous> (C:\qa\Automation\MyProj\Python Automation\Utilities\node\MyProjrtu\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at PartStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at HeaderParser.<anonymous> (C:\qa\Automation\MyProj\Python Automation\Utilities\node\MyProjrtu\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
```

Comment: Does it not work? How do you know? Read about [ask]

Comment: Thanks I updated question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node Multer unexpected field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31530200/node-multer-unexpected-field)

Answer (score 1):

in node.js change 
`upload.array()` 
to 
`upload.array('file')`

and in python :

`files = {'file': ('test_file', open(filePath, 'rb'))}` to

```
files = {'file':open(filepath,'rb')}
```

check answer from this post [Get image sent from post in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35755333/get-image-sent-from-post-in-node-js)